# Load shiny tabPanel in background

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyjs

I have several `tabPanel()` blocks in my shiny `ui.R` that all require a bit of time to load.  However, it appears that they are all treated as individual pages and only begin to render once the `tabPanel()` is select from the navigation bar.

Is there a way to pre-load those pages after the inital tab is loaded in the background?

I have tried to include the following at the bottom of my server function:

```
sapply(names(outputOptions(output)),function(x) outputOptions(output, x, suspendWhenHidden = FALSE))
```

This works for the output$variables that live outside of an observer or reactive context, but not for the ones inside.

#### Response to Victorp

I try to avoid placing `renderPlot` in an `observer` call when it makes sense, however I have a `reactiveVariable` data.frame  that is set through a file polling call that then needs to be subset and transformed.

That transformation is used in a series of plots.  It was structurally easier to place that `reactiveValue` in the `observer`, subset once, and then let all of the resulting plots use that non reactive subset.

```
  Data = reactivePoll(5479,
               session,
               checkFunc = function() {
                 if (file.exists(orderStatsPath))
                   file.info(orderStatsPath)$mtime[1]
                 else
                   ""
               },
               valueFunc = function() getData(orderStatsPath)
  )

  observe({

    Data = Data()
    Data = subset(Data, subset = Date >= Sys.Date() - 14)
    Data$Date = as.character(Data$Date)
    output$slippageRootTotalUSD = shiny::renderTable({
      result = dcast(Data,
                     Date ~ Symbol,
                     value.var = "slippageRootTotalUSD",
                     na.rm = T,
                     fun = sum,
                     margins = c("Date","Symbol"))

      rownames(result) = result[,1]
      result = signif(result[,-1],5)
      result
    },
    rownames = TRUE,
    hover = TRUE,
    digits = 2,
    spacing = 's'
    )

    output$SizeUSD = shiny::renderTable(
      {
        result = dcast(Data,
                       Date ~ Symbol,
                       value.var = "SizeUSD",
                       na.rm = T,
                       fun = sum,
                       margins = c("Date","Symbol"))

        rownames(result) = result[,1]
        result = round(result[,-1],0)

        result
      },
      rownames = TRUE,
      hover = TRUE,
      digits = 0,
      spacing = 's'
    )
    sapply(names(outputOptions(output)),function(x) outputOptions(output, x, suspendWhenHidden = FALSE))
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at `?outputOptions`, you probably want to use that :

```
# Disable suspend for output$myplot
outputOptions(output, "myplot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

Comment: Do you expect this to work even when the `output$plot` is assigned inside of and `observe` function?

Comment: Try to put the call to `outputOptions` in the same observer in which `output$plot` is assigned. In general, it's not recommended to assign output in observer, can't you do otherwise ? Can you provide an example ?

Comment: You also need to know that setting `suspendWhenHidden = FALSE` on an output created with `renderPlot` in an inactive tab doesn't work if height and width are not provided.

Comment: Well I have noticed the behavior is a bit sporadic.  It seems random whether or not the hidden tab plots are scaled correctly for the users resolution or if they load completely compressed on the left side.

Comment: This does not work for UI in shiny module even I put the function to app server part.